# Grid Alignment Issues

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What I need to produce is 3 grid items on the left and 2 grid items on the right. I tried using float on the second grid container but it didn't work the way I wanted to. The Grids also contain elements like Checkboxes so I'm not sure if that changes the alignment.

```
<Grid container xs={12} md={6}>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}> 1 </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}> 2</Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}> 3</Grid>
</Grid>
<Grid container xs={12} md={6}>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}> 4 </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={6}> 5</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Expected:
md:

```
1     4
2     5
3
```

Actual:

md:

```
1   4
2
    5
3
```

xs:

```
1 
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put both columns into another container and make them it's items:

```
  <Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>1</Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>2</Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>3</Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>4</Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>5</Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```